# Create shortcut from server to client can dynamically change path without replace client shortcut

Tags: excel, windows, server, client, shortcut

I have one server that contain my excel file for all client, every times I need to backup the excel file for example:

```
Name     |Date time
data.xls |4/12/2017
```

And the shortcut path was "\192.168.1.254\MyDocument\data.xls" when I backup the excel file become :

```
Name           |Date time
data.xls       |4/12/2017
data_copy1.xls |4/13/2017
```

And I was create the shortcut first time need to change the path become : "\192.168.1.254\MyDocument\data_copy1.xls"

Every time I change the path I go to client change one by one, is there some way to easier when I backup the excel file and the file name change and then the client shortcut follow the new path?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had found the answer:

so simple...

```
open notepad
type (@echo off)
type (start "" "path file"
save
choose extension All (*)
save with extension .bat
```

Know just copy the new path file for replace at

```
***path file***
```